# Integration Object Tracking Feature with OVR Integration Package in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, windows-mixed-reality

**GOAL**

I imported Meta XR Integration package and Meta XR Simulator.
Project platform is Android.

At play mixed reality mode, I want to track the object.

**CONTENT**

I use Built-in and Unity2022.3.8f1. I am using Meta XR Integration 57.0.

I tried for integrate AR feature in mixed reality mode but AR Foundation has some problems.

So I can't use AR Foundation.

What can I use for Object Tracking with OVR Integration in the mixed reality game?

**SOURCE URLS**

-Meta XR Integration

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/oculus-integration-deprecated-82022